# Javascript Error in CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I have JavaScript in CRM. When I Open one employee record, error is showing as below

```
"Ünable to get property 'Value' of undefined or null reference"
```

This error is showing only for few employee records. All other employee records are loading with out any error. So What could be wrong?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Well, the problem is that it's unable to get property 'Value' of undefined or null reference. Without seeing the code it's impossible to give any more specific help.

Comment: You likely have some `NULL` values in your database.

Comment: Any specific browser ? For any specific line of code ?

Comment: Please put some code so that we can understand the root cause. Now the error message is because you are requesting key "Value" to an undefined object. Go and search for *Value* in your relevant code

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the fact that only some records have this issue and from the mention of `Value` in the error, your code is likely attempting to read a field in a manner similar to this

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("<attribute name>").getValue().Value
```

But the attribute is empty, so `getValue()` returns `null`, so you get that error.

Off the top of my head, the attribute could be either OptionSet, Two Options, or Money (other types such as Single Line of Text do not have a `.Value` member)